# Jq can't seem to be able to read its own output?

Tags: shell, jq

Even stripped out of most decoration, this doesn't work - why ?

`echo "{}" | jq -scaM --unbuffered  | jq`

Comment: I love the freudian humor of `-scaM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest complete jq query is this:

```
echo "{}" | jq .
```

Do you want to append the periods and see how it'd go?

Comment: Yes, that works! As pointed out by @peak, jq's behaviour has changed with regards to that; with 1.5, it only defaults to the `.` query if stdin OR stdout is not a TTY - so when piping two jqs, no default query. 

https://github.com/hohl/sourcedrop-osx/issues/13 explains it.

I should also add that there's little use to my use-case... I just have this script that pipes some stuff into jq for pretty-printing, and it so happens that I was trying to pipe THAT script into jq for selecting/filtering. I simply modified my script to use the `.` query explicitly.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug/misfeature in jq 1.5 that explains the anomaly you evidently found (it has to do with the fact that your first invocation does not have an explicit filter).  Using a more recent version (available via github):

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.5rc2-146-gd228490

$ echo "{}" | jq -scaM --unbuffered | jq
[
  {}
]
```

Comment: jq-1.5rc2-146-gd228490 is more recent than 1.5? O_o

Comment: The important part is the SHA.  d228490 was committed on Jan 17.